# Align numbers in table with scientific notation and minus sign

Tags: siunitx, booktabs

I would like the numbers to be aligned by multiplication signs on this table. I have tried to use the option `table-format` in what it looks like the right way to me, but actually I haven't found any explanation about it in the booktabs documentation.

Are there other options I could use? And do you also know where to find a good documentation about them?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h!]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{lS[table-format=-1.1e-1]S[table-format=-1.1e-1]}
        \toprule
        & $m$ & $q$ \\
        \midrule
        Total death toll & \num{-9.8e-5} & \num{2.0e-1} \\
        Climatic hazards & \num{-1.0e-4} & \num{2.1e-1} \\
        Earthquakes & \num{6.0e-6}  & \num{-1.1e-2} \\
        Mass movements & \num{-1.8e-8} & \num{5.1e-5} \\
        Volcanic hazards & \num{-2.7e-7} & \num{5.4e-4} \\
        \bottomrule        
    \end{tabular}
\caption{Fit parameters for death toll per population and per year for the classes of geohazards.}
\label{t1}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: My unsatisfying result]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have nearly got it! You need to remove the `\num{...}` and just have the number.
See example below. For package documentation I like to use [CTAN](https://ctan.org/)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h!]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{lS[table-format=-1.1e-1]S[table-format=-1.1e-1]}
        \toprule
        & $m$ & $q$ \\
        \midrule
        Total death toll & -9.8e-5 & 2.0e-1 \\
        Climatic hazards & -1.0e-4 & 2.1e-1 \\
        Earthquakes & 6.0e-6  & -1.1e-2 \\
        Mass movements & -1.8e-8 & 5.1e-5 \\
        Volcanic hazards & -2.7e-7 & 5.4e-4 \\
        \bottomrule        
    \end{tabular}
\caption{Fit parameters for death toll per population and per year for the classes of geohazards.}
\label{t1}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I think I have just found out that 'S' columns are already made for numbers in the `\num{}` format...